# forcing initial callback despite dash.PreventUpdate preventing it from other function

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When a dash app is started, all callbacks should be fired according to the [dash documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks). But when callbacks are linked (ones output is the other ones input) the initial callback of the latter is prevented when the first raises a dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate or returns a dash.no_update.
Although I can somehow follow that logic, it was not clear for me that this would happen, **and I am interested in reading somewhere the reasons behind this**, although I have no idea where.

More practical, I would like to fire the initial callback nevertheless, is this possible? The code below is a minimal example of the problem:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Button('test', id='button'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='super', options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in ['test1', 'test2']]),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='under', options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in ['under1', 'under2']]),
        dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
])

@app.callback(
        Output('super', 'value'),
        Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
        prevent_initiall_call=True
)
def set_super_value(nclicks):
    if nclicks is None:
        return dash.no_update
    return 'test2'

@app.callback(
        Output('under', 'value'),
        Input('super', 'value')
)
def set_under_value(val):
    sleep(5)
    return 'under1'
    
@app.callback(
        Output('graph', 'figure'),
        Input('under', 'value'),
)
def make_figure(val):
    sleep(5)
    if val == 'under1':
        return go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0,1000), y=np.sin(np.arange(0,1000)/100)))
    else:
        return go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0,1000), y=np.cos(np.arange(0,1000)/100)))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the initial state:
[image]
And this is how I would like it to be:
[image]

In this simple example I can always set this initial value as the 'value' option in the initial app.layout variable, but the problem in my actual application makes this a suboptimal solution in my eyes.

* Edits made to the code to make specify the problem a little more specific. Code still works and screenshots still apply (but

Comment: Can you change the first callback to return a value strictly for the initialization? This example is quite simple, so it's hard to guess what might work for your actual application.

Comment: I updated a little bit. Updating the first callback is not possible I think (because it should start without any value) but I can copy the 'sleep(5)' function to the app.layout initialization. The 'problem' there is that the function is called in two locations (app.layout and second callback).

Comment: If the first one should start with no value, then you could `return None`.

Comment: Looks like there is no explanation from Dash on this, could be a bug, can you specify what you really want to achieve in your main project? we could figure out a turnaround on that.